# Remote Debugging in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have an application running in server A. The dev environment is in server B.
I am trying to do remote debugging of app running in server A.

In server A i added following command to service start script

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4554,server=y,suspend=n
```

And service is running in server A.

When i try to launch remote debugging configuration it gives

```
Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused. Connection refused
```

port 4554 is free in server A.

What other configuration need to be done for this?

Regards
Dheeraj Joshi

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this.

1. Set `suspend=y`, just to make sure you got the JVM line right. This should stop the VM on startup until you connect.
2. If you're on Unix, bring up the terminal and try `telnet [host] [port]` - this will quickly let you know if there's anything listening to that port on that host.
3. Make sure the connection properties in Eclipse are set correctly. Note that the port defaults to 8000.
4. Use the IP address instead of the host name, to rule out DNS/hostfile problems.

[image: Run properties in eclipse]

Another way of starting the JVM that I use successfully is:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y
```

Comment: It says name of the service not known.  ibm2.host.net/4554: Name or service not known

Comment: Sounds potentially like it can't resolve `ibm2.host.net` to an IP-address. Can you try using the host's IP address instead of host name?

Comment: Same message "Name or service not known"

Comment: What OS of the client and server?

Comment: did you try to telnet to the port?

Comment: If anyone is having troubles connecting to a remote linux server, an SSH tunnel solved the problem for me. 
ssh -L 10000:<serverIP>:8000 <user>@<serverIP>
You can now point your eclipse to localhost and port 10000. This connection will be tunneled to port 8000 on your server, where your JVM debugger is listening!

Answer (score 2):

Check if there is a firewall between and/or on the two servers.