# How to debug remote OSGi bundle?

Tags: eclipse, osgi, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm completely new to OSGi and I'm working on the development of an OSGi bundle and I want to debug my code (set breakpoints, step by step run, variable lookup, ...).

I have my virgo server listening on port 8001.

How can I do that ?

I'm using Springsource Tool Suite 3.0 and my bundle is running on a remote virgo server.

Thanks for any hint you can give me.

Marco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this answer, 
I'm sure that one will help you on this also: 
[Remote Debugging in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346018/remote-debugging-in-eclipse)